# Combining variables 2 x-variables to one

Tags: r

I would like to combine x-variables with lines since they were measured not at interrelated time periods with different colours of one mainline to denote the difference. Any suggestions to the following script?

```
plot(dat$days,dat$wc_10_1,
     main="Rollesbroich-1, 0.1 m",
     xlab="Days",
     ylab=expression( "water content (cm"^3 / "cm)"^3),
     type="l",
     col="blue",
     pch=16)
lines(dat$days,dat$m_wc_10_1, col="red",pch=16, type="l")
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible set of data

Comment: @borexino y1 [1, NA, NA, 5], y2 [NA, 2, 4, NA], y [1, 2, 3, 4]. Want to combine x1 and x2 against y but to keep line part formed by y2 in different colour compared to the line formed by y1.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably most easily done using `ggplot2`. Below a reproducible example of what I think you are trying to achieve assuming that both x-variables are continuous.

```
dat = data.frame(days=1:10, 
                 wc_10_1=rnorm(10),
                 m_wc_10_1=rnorm(10,5,5))

# ggplot2 ----
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x=days, y=wc_10_1, colour=m_wc_10_1)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(
    x="Days",
    y=expression(cm^{3} / cm)
  )
```

Unsure how to supply a continuous scale to lines using base plot, but I'm sure it's possible. A workaround would be to use `type="b"`:

```
# base ----
my_colour = "blue"
x2_norm = dat$m_wc_10_1 - min(dat$m_wc_10_1)
x2_norm = x2_norm/max(x2_norm)
my_colour_scale = scales::alpha(my_colour, x2_norm)
plot(x=dat$days,
     y=dat$wc_10_1,
     col=my_colour_scale,
     t="b",
     pch=16)
```